# How to identify author in wordpress comments?

Tags: functions, comments

I want to give a prominence in the comments for the authors of the articles in wordpress, I tried to find a class to be able to personalize, but I could not identify any difference between the normal comments for those of authors.

[image]

What I searched for is something in function.php

Comment: Create a custom `comments.php` check https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/comments.php

Comment: I've already created it, but I do not know how I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Comments of post author are given a class `bypostauthor` , you can personalize it through css.

Comment: This class does not exist, I am creating a new template.

Comment: In your template add `<?php comment_class(); ?>` to your comment div/li element

Comment: But this tag does not identify the author, more would put in all the "li".

Comment: It will just add a class to the comments. More info in codex [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class) .